# Adding layers in QGIS with predefined order in TOC and also make some of them to have visibility turned off when added

Tags: qgis, order

I am working on a project and I have a lot of shapefiles with the same name but with different data and when I add them to QGIS they are sorted randomly in TOC (Layers Panel).

Can I configure their order? So when I add them, they are sorted based on some rule or based on type of the layer?

And can I configure that some of them are hidden(visibility turned off) when added?

Comment: How many times are you going to be doing this? Seems this is a problem with your data organization rather than a feature enhancement for QGIS!

Comment: How can I organize data before I add them to QGIS? when you have e.g. several files, all of them contain 20 shapefiles (same name different spatial data) and when you add them to to QGIS they are sorted randomly

Comment: Sorry I was being snarky - but  - What I mean is, are you able to organize all your data once in QGIS in the order you're after, then save the QGIS project, and always use that project for this data? Or... are you always getting new datasets and always going to have to organize them as such?

Comment: No biggie :) That I can do, but that is not what I need. My assignment is to have a blank map document where I add those shapefiles with same name but different spatial data and they will get automatically in desired order.

Comment: I have folders that contain 20 shapefiles, Shapefiles have same name but contain different spatial data. I have prepared layer files for these shapefiles that contain information about style of the features etc. And this project is for people that will get blank map document and as many folders with shapefiles as they want.

Comment: And they can add as many shapefiles to the map document as they want, but when I prepare order for on set of shapefiles, the first set will be sorted how I saved the project before, but when they add another set, the layers will be disordered and I cannot set the order for many layers, that just would not look good and I just cannot do it like that.

Comment: Damn it is hard for me to explain it :D Now I am sure I just confused you

Comment: I will read that again tomorrow...!

Comment: still not really understanding what you're doing, but I think you're going to have a hard time using QGIS in this manner with your data structure / organization, etc...